# Is even better use jQuery handler?

Tags: jquery, html, css, event-handling

I mean, if I have this handler :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myElement').change(function() {
        // some
    });             
});
```

linked to "400" elements for example, it will be slower than

```
function myFunct() {
    // some
{

<select class="myElement'" onchange="myFunct(this);return false">
    // one of 400 elements. Each of this use that onchange link
</select>
```

because in fact I need to call that function only when I "change" somethings (so I don't understand why I need to handle 400 elements, worst of resource).

What do you think about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it will be slower since the browser must attach a handler all of those elements, which could cause a "lag" on page load during which your user might be able to interact with elements which have no handler code attached to them.

You can still use jQuery in a performant way, however, using just one [*delegated*](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) handler.

```
$('#container').delegate(".myElement", "change", function () {
    myFuct(this);
    return false;
});
```

Update! jQuery 1.7 example (using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)):

```
$('#container').on("change", ".myElement", function () {
    myFuct(this);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @markzzz - Yes, it attaches only to a specified parent element and checks if the click has bubbled up from an element matching the selector passed in as the first argument.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
$(function() {

    function myFunct() { ... }

    $('.myElement').change( myFunct ); 

});
```

The trick is to define **one** function object, and then use that one function as the change handler for all your elements.

Comment: This will still attach separate click handlers to those 400 elements.

Comment: @karim Are you sure? The way I see it, there is only one function object - `myFunct`, ergo, there is one handler. Every of those 400 elements will have a reference to that handler (which *is* a downer), but again, there is only one handler, right?

Comment: Uhm yes...but in fact I've handle 400 elements that maybe I'll never use (so a worst of resource). Else, I can easy call a function only when is necessary :)

Comment: @Šime Vidas - true, just one function object attached to all of those elements - I was referring to the fact that the browser must register a click handler on all those elements (the *downer* you were referring to). I didn't make it clear enough in my comment, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

I think that second one is better in this case. You can use jQuery inside your function, too

http://jsperf.com/testaaa

jQuery's call: 67,194/sec

your function calls: 114,142,715/sec

Comment: ? Don't know the source of these test :O I do attack nothing to "onchange" for each select...why 114,142,715/sec?

Comment: But of what? On the second example there isn't any kind of attach/handler :O